# JQuery Datatable + Ajax: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to display a custom error message inside the JQuery Datatable. What should happen is: I capture the most common error codes, then display a custom error message inside the cell.

The code looks as follows.

JS:

```
            $element.find('#tabla-recibos').DataTable({
                autowidth: true,
                pageLength: 5,
                ajax: {
                    url: '/api/recibos/dni/' + $ctrl.dniUser,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataSrc: '',
                    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log(exception);
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        200: function() {
                            console.log('200 OK')
                        },
                        204: function() {
                            console.log('204 Sin Sin datos')
                        },
                        400: function() {
                            console.log('400 Solicitud incorrecta');
                            $('#tabla-recibos tbody')
                                .empty()
                                .append('<tr><td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty data-translate="errors">Ha ocurrido un problema al tratar de cargar los recibos</td></tr>')
                        },
                        500: function() {
                            console.log('500 Error interno del servidor');
                            $('#tabla-recibos tbody')
                                .empty()
                                .append('<tr><td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty" data-translate="errors">Ha ocurrido un problema al tratar de cargar los recibos</td></tr>')
                        }
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                    //                      { data: "id" },
                    {
                        data: "numRecibo"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "numPoliza"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "importe",
                        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '', ' €')
                    },
                    {
                        data: "fechaPago",
                        "render": function(data) {
                            var locale = $locale.id;
                            return (moment(data).isValid()) ? moment(data).locale(locale).format("L") : "-";
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "estado"
                    }
                ],
                language: {
                    url: obtenerIdioma()
                },
                initComplete: function(settings, json) {

                    //var table = angular.element('#tabla-recibos').DataTable(options);

                }
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table id="tabla-recibos" class="table table-hover dataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!-- <th style="display:none;"><span data-translate="global.field.id">Id</th> -->
                    <th><span data-translate="webclientesApp.recibo.numRecibo">NÃºm. Recibo</th>
                    <th><span data-translate="webclientesApp.recibo.numPoliza">NÃºm. PÃ³liza</th>
                    <th><span data-translate="webclientesApp.recibo.importe">Importe</th>
                    <th><span data-translate="webclientesApp.recibo.fechaPago">Fecha de Pago</th>
                    <th><span data-translate="webclientesApp.recibo.estado">Estado</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty" data-translate="errors">{{language.emptyTable}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my test case (I'm using JHipster) I should capture a "204 No data", then modify the table accordingly.

The problem: whenever I launch the view, I get this error as soon as it starts:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
    at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.js:3899)
    at fire (jquery.js:3243)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3373)
    at done (jquery.js:9098)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9340)
```

I can't find a similar question which fixes my issue. I followed [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21613/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-error-of-undefined), but wasn't very helpful, at least in my case.

Comment: Hey again wickedchild, it sounds like you are not getting any response from the server at all. Look at the source around line [**3899**](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L3899) `var error = json.error || json.sError;` and the error thrown is "*Cannot read property 'error' of undefined*" === You are not getting any response ...`json` is undefined. I guess `$ctrl.dniUser` not is set when you load the page, but I can only guess.

Comment: Hey @davidkonrad, 'sup? Yes, what you suggest seems to be the issue. I was looking into the JSON provided by the backend, and there's some unreported changes going on. As a result, the JSON seems to be missing right now... Thanks for the help!